# How to tail multiple files using tail -0f in Linux/AIX

Tags: tail

I tried tailing two files using the option:

```
tail -0f file1.log -0f file2.log
```

In Linux I see an error "tail : can process only one file at a time".

In AIX I see the error as "Invalid options".

This works fine when I use:

```
tail -f file1 -f file 2
```

in Linux but not in AIX.

I want to be able to tail multiple files using `-0f` or `-f` in AIX/Linux

`multitail` is not recognized in either of these OS.

Comment: Have you tried to use `screen` to create two different sessions? You should be able to use tail on both screens? Also, `tmux` can do the job as well if you have it installed.

Answer (score 56):

What about:

```
tail -f file1 & tail -f file2
```

Or prefixing each line with the name of the file:

```
tail -f file1 | sed 's/^/file1: /' &
tail -f file2 | sed 's/^/file2: /'
```

To follow all the files whose name match a pattern, you could implement the `tail -f` (which reads from the file every second continuously) with a `zsh` script like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
zmodload zsh/zselect
zmodload zsh/system
set -o extendedglob

typeset -A tracked
typeset -F SECONDS=0

pattern=${1?}; shift

drain() {
  while sysread -s 65536 -i $1 -o 1; do
    continue
  done
}

for ((t = 1; ; t++)); do
  typeset -A still_there
  still_there=()
  for file in $^@/$~pattern(#q-.NoN); do
    stat -H stat -- $file || continue
    inode=$stat[device]:$stat[inode]
    if
      (($+tracked[$inode])) ||
        { exec {fd}< $file && tracked[$inode]=$fd; }
    then
      still_there[$inode]=
    fi
  done
  for inode fd in ${(kv)tracked}; do
    drain $fd
    if ! (($+still_there[$inode])); then
      exec {fd}<&-
      unset "tracked[$inode]"
    fi
  done
  ((t <= SECONDS)) || zselect -t $((((t - SECONDS) * 100) | 0))
done
```

Then for instance, to follow all the text files in the current directory recursively:

```
that-script '**/*.txt' .
```

Comment: any reason to prefer the `sed` way over the `&` way?

Comment: @giladmayani  I'm just experimenting with this but the problem with the & way that I found is that if you wrap it in a script you will get ghost processes that don't quit.

Comment: Doesn't tail accept multiple files and regex?

Comment: @JustinGoldberg [POSIX tail](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tail.html) takes only  one file. I'm not sure what `tail` would do with a regex.

Answer (score 47):

In OSX and Linux, using

```
tail -f <file1> <file2>
```

works great for me.  Another nice thing is that it has the following output:

```
==> /srv/www/my-app/shared/log/nginx.access.log <==
things from log 1

==> /srv/www/my-app/shared/log/nginx.error.log <==
things from log 2

==> /srv/www/my-app/shared/log/nginx.access.log <==
new things from log 1
```

to help you recognize which output is from which log.

Comment: add `q` to supress the headers

Answer (score 18):

`tail` multiple files is extended by GNU tail version. With AIX, you don't have GNU tail, so you can't do it. You can use `multitail` instead.

You can install [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/download.php) in both Linux and AIX.

- With AIX, you can download package [here](http://www.vanheusden.com/aix/).
- In Linux, `multitail` is often in repo, so you can install it easily using distro package manager:

  - In Debian/Ubuntu: `apt-get install multitail`
  - In Centos/Fedora: `yum install multitail`

Comment: Multitail works nice and syntax is simple: `multitail -i path/to/file1 -i path/to/file2`

Comment: Nice find! Any idea how to redirect the output of `multitail`? I only managed to use it in interactive mode...

Answer (score 8):

The following thing works fine to output things on std out

```
tail -f file1 & tail -f file2
```

I wanted to `pipe` the output to another process. In above case `&` was making the part before it run in the background and only second part was being `piped` to process

so I used

```
tail -f file1 file2 | process
```

@Stéphane your answer is perfect, but just mentioning my use case which has a little twist.

Comment: The point is that `tail -f file1 file2` doesn't work on AIX where tail accepts only one filename. You can do `(tail -f file1 & tail -f file2) | process` to redirect the stdout of both `tail`s to the pipe to `process`.

Comment: This worked for me tail -100f log1.log & tail -100f log2.log

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a code snippet using `tmux` that can give you two different windows you can use to tail both files simultaneously:

```
tmux new-window -a -n Tail
tmux new-session -d -s Tail -n SSH0 -d
tmux selectp -t Tail

#This is tmux interactions with the user (colors of the tabs used, hot keys, etc.)
tmux bind-key -n M-Left previous-window -t WinSplit
tmux bind-key -n M-Right next-window -t WinSplit
tmux set-window-option -g monitor-activity on
tmux set -g visual-activity on
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg blue
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-fg red
tmux set -g pane-border-fg yellow
tmux set -g pane-active-border-bg red
tmux set -g message-fg yellow
tmux set -g message-bg red
tmux set -g message-attr bright
tmux set -g status-left "#[fg=red]#S"

#Names two seperate windows
tmux new-window -n tail1 -t Tail
tmux new-window -n tail2 -t Tail

#Now this will allow you to automatically run tail when this tmux script is run
tmux send-keys -t Tail:0 'tail -f file1.log' C-m
tmux send-keys -t Tail:1 'tail -f file2.log' C-m
```

UPDATE: Using `screen` can also attach/detach multiple sessions so you can run `tail` multiple times as well. I can suggest doing this:

`screen -s Tail_Server1.log`

Next you would want to hold `CTRL+A+D` to dettach without killing the sessions and then next:

```
screen -s Tail_Server2.log
```

Both will run two seperate `screens`, I would refer to `screen --help` so you can adjust it to how you want both screens to work on your `terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me on SunOS 5.10.

```
$ tail -f file1.log &
$ tail -f file2.log &
$
```

Both tails will run in background. The changes to files will be thrown to stdout. Moreover you can run any command in between just by hitting enter.

Comment: ...but that creates two processes that you have to kill and mixes STDOUT with foreground output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following oneliner:

`while true; do cat /path/to/numerous/folders/and/files/*/*.txt | grep "some filter" | tail -n 10; sleep 1; done`

Every 1 second, the script will print 10 last lines of the filtered stream.

To break the loop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux and OSX, supposed the files are in a different locations like these:

- logs/nginx/nginx-access.log
- logs/nginx/nginx-error.log
- logs/php/php-error.log
- logs/php/php-fpm-error.log

With the above logs, while inside the `logs/` directory, you can use this command:

```
tail -f {php/php-{,fpm-}error,nginx/nginx-{access,error}}.log
```

Or you can use a wildcard to tail everything inside the logs/ directory

```
tail -f {nginx,php}/*.log
```